# Angular ngStyle acting weird in a custom button, grid system not working with parent and child components

Tags: css, angular

I made a custom button using `ngStyle` passing CSS properties from the button component to the button HTML view. The properties `color`, `background`, and `border-radius` work but the properties `grid-column` and `grid-row` don't work.

The original, non-custom buttons are placed correctly in the grid, using values passed from the component using `ngStyle`.

I'm thinking that the custom button is a child component, i.e., the styling

*parent*

```html
style="display: grid; grid-template-columns: repeat(24, 1fr); gap: 2px;"
```

is in the parent component and the

*child*

```html
style="grid-column': 7/ span 3; grid-row: 3/span 1;"
```

is in the child component. In other words, the grid depends on CSS properties in the parent and child components, when `color` and `background` are CSS properties in the child, not dependent on the parent.

Thinking aloud here...the child component is its own HTML template, unaware of CSS properties in the parent HTML template. Putting `display: grid; grid-template-columns: repeat(24, 1fr)` in the child won't work. I need to pass the `grid-column` and `grid-row` from the child to the parent, in other words, tell the parent HTML where the custom button goes. I can do this with `@Output` and an event emitter, on page load with `ngOnInit`.

The event emitter will pass the grid coordinates from the child to the parent, then I can use the grid coordinates with `ngStyle` like this:

```html
<span [ngStyle]="style_b()">
    <app-phoneme-button text="b" (btnClick)="btnClick($event)" (gridColumn)="gridColumn($event)"
            [homeToolbarObject]="homeToolbarObject"></app-phoneme-button>
</span>
```

That puts sets the `grid-column-start` and the `grid-column-end` correctly for the span, with the button in the span, but the button still ends short, i.e., the button has an incorrect `grid-column-end`. And it's smelly code to use two `ngStyle` settings.

Here's my custom button.

*phoneme-button.component.html*

```html
<button
    (click)="onClick()"
    [ngStyle]="stylePhoneme"
    *ngIf="language2.short==='en' || language2.short==='zh' || language2.short==='fi' || language2.short==='ipa'"
    mat-raised-button>
    <span>{{buttonText}}</span>&nbsp;<span>{{exampleWords}}</span>
    <span (click)='playAudio(text)'><mat-icon appHeadphonesIcon aria-hidden="false"
        aria-label="Headphones icon">headphones</mat-icon></span>
</button>
```

*consonant-chart.component.html*

```html
<mat-card appearance="outlined" style="display: grid; grid-template-columns: repeat(24, 1fr); gap: 2px;">

   <app-phoneme-button text="b" 
     (btnClick)="btnClick($event)" 
     [homeToolbarObject]="homeToolbarObject" >
   </app-phoneme-button>

</mat-card>
```

*phoneme-button.component.ts*

```js
import { Component, OnInit, Input, Output, EventEmitter } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-phoneme-button',
  templateUrl: './phoneme-button.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./phoneme-button.component.css']
})
export class PhonemeButtonComponent implements OnInit{

    @Input()
    set text(name: string) {
        this.buttonText = name;
    switch (this.buttonText) {
      case 'b':
        this.exampleWords = "base";
        break;
        default:
          this.exampleWords = null;
    }
    }
    get name(): string | null {
        return this.buttonText;
    }

  stylePhoneme: any  =  {
    'color': 'white',
    'background': 'red',
    'border-radius': '0',
    'grid-column': '7/ span 3',
    'grid-row': '3/span 1',
  };

  onClick() {
        this.btnClick.emit(this.buttonText);
  }

...
}
```

Using `grid-column-start` and `grid-column-end` didn't help.

Taking `[ngStyle]="stylePhoneme"` out of the custom button and putting the styling into the button:

*consonant-chart.component.html*

```html
<app-phoneme-button text="b" 
  style="grid-column: 1 / span 2; grid-row: 1 / span 1;"
  (btnClick)="btnClick($event)" 
  [homeToolbarObject]="homeToolbarObject" >
</app-phoneme-button>
```

puts the button in the right row, with the right `grid-column-start`, but `grid-column-end` doesn't work. This suggests that the custom button can be placed in the right column and row by the parent, but the child sets where the button ends.

Putting the styling in the custom button didn't work:

```html
<button
    style="background: red; grid-column: 7/ span 3; grid-row: 1/ span 1;">
    <span>{{buttonText}}</span>
</button>
```

Answer (score 1):

When you look at the generated HTML (with your browser's dev tools), it will look something like this:

```
<mat-card ...>
  <app-phoneme-button ...>
    <button ...>
      ...
    </button>
  </app-phoneme-button>
</mat-card>
```

No what I think is going on is that the mat-card is the grid container, and the app-phoneme-button is the child. So if you wanna set any grid properties, you will have to do it on app-phoneme-button.

If you wanna do that from within the phoneme component, you could do this by using a @HostBinding there. I would advise against it, since your button could be used elsewhere where it might not be a child of a grid container.

Regarding this:

> but grid-column-end doesn't work

Ok, I fiddled with it a bit and it does work, but maybe it doesn't look like it works since the button doesn't have a width, so changing the column-end property doesn't really do much except moving other objects.

So, in your phoneme-button.component.css you could put something like this:

```
:host {
  width: 100%;
}

button {
  width: 100%;
}
```

Here's a little example for you to see if this is what you're looking for:

```css
mat-card {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(24, 1fr);
  gap: 2px;
}

button {
  color: white;
  background: red;
  border-radius: 0;
  width: 100%;
}

app-phoneme-button {
  grid-column: 7/ span 3;
  grid-row: 3 / span 1;
  width: 100%;
}

div {
  width: 10px;
  height: 10px;
  background-color: green;
  margin: 5px;
}
```

```html
<mat-card>

   <div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div> <div>  </div>   <div> </div>

   <app-phoneme-button >
     <button>
       <span>buttonText</span>
     </button>
   </app-phoneme-button>
   
   <div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div> <div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div>

</mat-card>
```